# Bouncing effect in d3

Tags: d3.js

Does anybody know if it's possible to create a bouncing effect on an SVG element (circle) in D3 using for example transitions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using the .ease("bounce") or .ease("elastic") after .transition() you can achieve that effect. note that bounce and elastic are similar but not the same.
in this (imo) really good guide you can find some good examples for d3, i used them myself to learn it http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920026938.do